# Get dynamically generated ids with jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

new here and would like some help.
I'm working on a project and where I created some elements with dynamically generated ids but I can't tailor my existing code to work with dynamic ids.
Here is my HTML:

[image: Sorry I couldn't paste my code here]

And here is my working JS script:

```
 $('#headline1').keyup(updateCount).keydown(updateCount);
  document.getElementById("headline1").addEventListener("change", updateCount);

 function updateCount() {
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    $('#countHeadline1').text(cs);
    cs = $(this).val();
    $('#headlineText1').text(cs);
  }
```

And here is what I tried among other solutions but nothing seems to work:

```
var c = 1,
var headline1 = "headline1" + c;
var countHeadline1 = "countHeadline1" + c;
var headlineText1 = "headlineText1" + c;
$('#' + headline1).keyup(updateCount).keydown(updateCount);
 document.getElementById("headline1" + c).addEventListener("change", updateCount);

function updateCount() {
   var cs = $(this).val().length;
   $('#' + countHeadline1).text(cs);
   cs = $(this).val();
   $('#' + headlineText1).text(cs);
 }
 c += 1;
```

Thank you,

EDIT: here is the code that create the element on click on a button:

```
jQuery('#add').on('click', function() {
  c += 1;
  jQuery('#parent').append('<hr><div>Headline 1:<br /><div><INPUT TYPE="text" placeholder="Headline" onkeydown="javascript:stripspaces(this)" id="headline1'+ c +'" maxlength="30" style="width: 350px;float:left;min-height: 32px;"><span id="countHeadline1'+ c +'" class="adCounter" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);float:left;position: inherit;margin-left: 0px;">0</span></div></div>');
});
```

Comment: could you add your html too? or create a fiddle.

Comment: The html is in the image. I couldn't add it directly here. Sorry I don't know how to use fiddle, I'm really new to this but I want to learn.

Comment: if element with id = "countHeadline1" is dynamic, when it is getting generated? add those details so we can understand it better.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: during creation of the dynamic html add a common class to the element

Comment: I'm generating a div by clicking on a button that contain similar code, but the ids are different and I have to make the code working on all the divs created

Comment: I have a button I click that create my div that contain an element id="headline11", and if click it again it will create id="headline12". My code works with id="headline1" that is the first div the user interact with without generating having to generate new divs, but I want to make this code work for the generated ones.

Comment: What about using CSS classes and event delegation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is using [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically created elements.

Another approach is the feature [`data-attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) along with the function [`$data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) which stores useful information, in this case, the current `id` of the created element.

Additionally, this approach uses the CSS class `inputs` to identify the textfields and bind the event [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) to execute the function `updateCount` for any changes on those textfields.

```js
function updateCount() {
  var identifier = $(this).data('identifier'); //'data attribute' along with function 'data'.
  $('#countHeadline1' + identifier).text($(this).val().length);
  $('#headlineText1' + identifier).text($(this).val());
}

var c = 1;
$('#add').on('click', function() {
  c += 1;
  $('#parent').append('<br><br><br>Headline ' + c + ':<br /><INPUT TYPE="text" class="inputs" data-identifier="' + c + '" placeholder="Headline" id="headline1' + c + '" maxlength="30" style="width: 350px;float:left;min-height: 32px;"/><span id="countHeadline1' + c + '" class="adCounter" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);float:left;position: inherit;margin-left: 0px;">0</span><br><span id="headlineText1' + c + '" class="headLine" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);float:left;position: inherit;margin-left: 0px;">0</span>');
});

$('#parent').on('input', '.inputs', updateCount); // Event delegation
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
  Headline 1:
  <br>
  <INPUT class='inputs' TYPE="text" data-identifier='1' placeholder="Headline" id="headline11" maxlength="30" style="width: 350px;float:left;min-height: 32px;" />
  <span id="countHeadline11" class="adCounter" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);float:left;position: inherit;margin-left: 0px;">
      0
    </span><br>
    <span id="headlineText11" class="headLine" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);float:left;position: inherit;margin-left: 0px;">
      0
    </span>
</div><br>
<button id='add'>Add</button>
```

**Important:** I've removed this `onkeydown="javascript:stripspaces(this)"`, so you need to decide where to call that function.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted to achieve, I'll have to personnalise it to all the other inputs I've but this helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after your edit, seeing that you have complete control over the HTML that's generated, I would definitely recommend going away from using IDs. Probably the easiest way would be to add classes to the `headline` and `headlineText` elements, and use them.

So, first, add classes to the elements that need them, when appending them in the click handler:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" placeholder="Headline" onkeydown="javascript:stripspaces(this)" id="headline1'+ c +'" maxlength="30" style="width: 350px;float:left;min-height: 32px;" class="headline">

<span id="headlineText1'+ c +'" class=headline-text>
```

Then you can bind the change event on all elements with the `headline` class (You shouldn't need to bind to `keyup` and `keydown` as long as you've bound to `change`):

```
$(".headline").change(updateCount);
```

You can then update the count using jQuery's `next` method, and update the text using the `parent` and `find` methods:

```
function updateCount() {
    var this$ = $(this);
    var val = this$.val();
    var cs = val.length;

    this$.next().text(cs);

    //Go up to the grandparent, which is the main div that wraps everything added in a single click, then search inside that for the element with the headline-text class
    this$.parent().parent().find(".headline-text").text(val);
}
```

This makes some assumptions about the structure of the HTML that's being added, but if you need to change that structure, it would only take minor changes to this code to work with it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any problem with the incrementation I have put the c variable there just so you now what I'm at. The code still not work. I'll for sure try your solution even if I'm a bit lost as I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: In the code that you provided, you only increment `c` a single time, and don't do anything with it after it's incremented. If you mean that your actual code is doing something differently than what you showed us, we'll need to see what the actual code is, to be able to understand why it might not be working.

Comment: c is incremented everytime i click on the buton to create a new element

Comment: I've edited my initial post with the code that creates the element and increment c. Thank you

Comment: Okay, I completely changed my answer based on the latest edit. Seeing that you have access to the HTML that's generated makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I understand using IDs seems like a `direct` way to target elements, but it might be more and more complicated as you keep adding content or elements to your app/page, so try to think of html as a structured set of elements that can have "patterns" or "templates", like this:

```
<div class="headline">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="headlineCount">0</span>
  <span class="headlineText">Text</span>
</div>
```

With this in mind, lets check some important concepts of using JavaScript with HTML, that jQuery eases a lot

1. You can "traverse" HTML as a `tree`, with parents and children leafs (you might want to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction))
2. You can select elements using more than just IDs (you might want to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)).
3. Interacting with HTML inputs trigger events (you might want to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events))

Using html as the one stated above, you can have this:

```
<div class="headline">
  <input type="text" value="One">
  <span class="headlineCount">0</span>
  <span class="headlineText">Headline One</span>
</div>
<div class="headline">
  <input type="text" value="Two">
  <span class="headlineCount">0</span>
  <span class="headlineText">Two</span>
</div>
```

Two groups of class `headline`, each contains the input field, the count number and the text.

And with jQuery you can use code like this:

```
function update () {
    var inputElement = this
    $(inputElement).nextAll('.headlineCount').text(inputElement.value);
    $(inputElement).nextAll('.headlineText').text(inputElement.value);
}    
jQuery('.headline input').on('change', update)
```

Which basically reads like:

```
jQuery('.headline input').on('change', update)
```

For all `input` elements that are inside any element with class `headline`, attach a `change` event listener with `update` function.

```
function update () {
    var inputElement = this
    $(inputElement).nextAll('.headlineCount').text(inputElement.value);
    $(inputElement).nextAll('.headlineText').text(inputElement.value);
}
```

The `update` function when triggered, will receive the `<input>` element as "context" (*CHECK NOTE*) and the `this` "variable" will refer to it.

Then with jQuery we do:

```
$(inputElement).nextAll('.headlineCount').text(inputElement.value);
```

Which means: starting from the input element find all elements with class `headlineCount` that are **AFTER** it, and change its text to the `value` of the input element.

I hope this small explanation is enough to get you started, indeed you're starting to handle some of the most important concepts of Front-End development, please don't stop refering to Mozilla documentation site (MDN) its wonderful.

**NOTE**: The `this` keyword is a somewhat advanced topic, to start I highly recommend to think of it as a "context" reference. But make sure to check it in MDN too!

---

Edit: now with Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3w7t1bhm/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain as you did, it's really appreciated.  I think that this won't apply to my case, I might be mistaken, what changes with my case is the id value and not the html element value. I don't know if I'm missing something but it doesn't seem to solve my issue here. Thank you much.

Comment: No problem, I'm sorry if I assumed a few things. I added a demo of it.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm pretty new to JS and I had big struggles to make my code works and if I use another logic, what I've done will break and I would have to start over. Is there any way my existing code can work with the same logic?

Comment: I understand that. I think it might be doable: if you had some elements already in the page, your function `updateCount` would work if instead of using the same variable `countHeadline1` you "extract" the id from the `this` element (`$(this).attr('id')`) and use that.

But you have a bigger problem: you have an element that when clicked you're adding NEW headlines. You will need to add event handlers to these too.

So you will end up: creating elements and adding event handlers to them.

Comment: Maybe you could try a more "classic" approach: use `onchange` directly on your html element: `<input onchange="updateCount(this)" id="headline1">` and same for updateCount: extract the number from the id, and use that to target the label.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I really don't understand because of my limited JS knowledge. The "this" thing is Chinese to me . I'm just trying to make this work with what I already have. I'm not trying to improve or optimize it. Your effort is really appreciated.

Comment: Hey, dw. Sorry if I wasn't as clear as I wanted. Here, check this one: https://jsfiddle.net/j08ncm3L/ the key parts are the `onchange` used in the input and how its "extracting" the `num` from the id